# Firebase deploy works in the console but not in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: node.js, firebase, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to deploy my webapp to firebase hosting through a bitbucket pipeline, It's not deploying correctly in the pipeline but in the console it works no problem. This is what I do in the console:

```
npm run build
firebase login:ci
firebase deploy --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

In the pipeline I'm running this YAML script:

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
        - step:
            name: Install and Build App
            caches:
              - node
            script:
              - npm install
              - CI=false npm run build
            artifacts:
              - build/
        - step:
            name: Deploy App to Firebase
            deployment: production
            script:
              - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:0.6.0
                variables:
                  KEY_FILE: $KEY_FILE
                  PROJECT_ID: $PROJECT_ID
```

I think it might have to do with the .firebaserc but I'm not sure. this is the .firebaserc:

```
firebase target:apply hosting $PROJECT_ID $DOMAIN
```

Maybe someone can shed some light on why this isn't working, I'm new to pipeline scripts and I don't really see  the issue, it succeeds in deploying to firebase hosting but It's not working at all on the actual domain.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command firebase login:ci that should generate a TOKEN, you add that token in Bitbucket in your Repository Settings > Repository Variables. What ever name you choose should match your pipeline. In my example I use FIREBASE_TOKEN_CI. When I commit my changes to bitbucket, it runs the pipeline, builds and deploys.

You can always modify your script in your package.json so in your cli you can run `npm run build:prod` like you would run `npm run start`, etc and use the build:prod in the yml.
here is an example:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod=true"
    }
```

CODE BELOW is a pipeline.yml I use for Ionic/Angular
NOTE: Artifacts is the folder your build files are generated after running build. Angular is called dist, so you might use dist/. My example uses www/** that is Ionics build output. You have some CI=False in your example, I have not seen that nor use that and my project builds and deploys. My second script is for cloud functions

```
- cd functions
   - npm install
   - cd ..
```

you can omit that part if you don't have functions. I have recently had a error about OAuth and I had to generate a new token with login:ci and replace my token, and it was working again for deploy. Hope this helps anyone. I had problems at first also and found a working format that I can adapt to other frameworks.

---

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
 default:
   - step:
       name: Install, Build
       caches:
         - node
       deployment: test
       script:
         - npm install
         - npm run build:prod
       artifacts: 
         - www/**
   - step:
       name: Deploy to Firebase
       deployment: production
       script:
         - cd functions
         - npm install
         - cd ..
         - pipe: atlassian/firebase-deploy:0.3.4
           variables:
             FIREBASE_TOKEN: '$FIREBASE_TOKEN_CI'
```

Comment: Just a not if anyone reads this answer above. Bitbucket pipeline will now give a warning FIREBASE_TOKEN is deprecated due to its legacy. For better auth use google service account KEY_FILE. Hope it helps anyone else.

Comment: [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1388816/tony-b) Hey can you help me with new way to setup this pipline

Comment: Tinkeshwar Singh post your pipeline code, there are 2 examples above already posted that would work in most cases.

Comment: @TinkeshwarSingh just tagging so you get my reply